# PHP API Curl header does not have the authorisation field passing through

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have built a PHP API and added the Curl code below to send through the authorisation in the header

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://MyWebSite.com/v2/APIlanding",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5OjU0NjU0NjU0NjU0NjU0",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Length: 0",
    "Host: MyWebSite.com",
    "Postman-Token: 844ea690-ee71-4e8e-bdc6-8ee73992ee9a,76a1d1c9-b571-4557-a162-c1f0b7660e50",
    "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.18.0",
    "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));
```

The problem is that not all the header values are being passed through?

Could someone please advise why this is the case?

This is the value that is coming through to the API landing point.

```
Results: Array
(
   [USER-AGENT] => PostmanRuntime/7.18.0
   [POSTMAN-TOKEN] => 844ea690-ee71-4e8e-bdc6-8ee73992ee9a,76a1d1c9-b571-4557-a162-c1f0b7660e50
   [CACHE-CONTROL] => no-cache, no-cache
   [ACCEPT-ENCODING] => gzip, deflate
   [ACCEPT] => */*
   [CONNECTION] => close
   [X-ACCEL-INTERNAL] => /internal-nginx-static-location
   [X-REAL-IP] => xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   [HOST] => MyWebSite.com
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works returns all headers with this...

```
<?php

//REQUEST

function get_web_page( $url,$curl_data )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $curl_data,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Accept: */*",
            "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
            "Authorization: Basic MTIzNDU2Nzg5OjU0NjU0NjU0NjU0NjU0",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
            "Connection: keep-alive",
            "Content-Length: 0",
            "Host: MyWebSite.com",
            "Postman-Token: 844ea690-ee71-4e8e-bdc6-8ee73992ee9a,76a1d1c9-b571-4557-a162-c1f0b7660e50",
            "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.18.0"
        )   
    );

    $ch      = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err     = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg  = curl_error($ch) ;
    $header  = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

  //  $header['errno']   = $err;
  //  $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
  //  $header['content'] = $content;

    return $content;
}

$curl_data = "";
$url = "http://MyWebSite.com/v2/APIlanding";
$response = get_web_page($url,$curl_data);

print '<pre>';
print_r($response); 
print '</pre>';

?>



<?php

// BACKEND

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}  

?>
```